# 3d graph (x, y , z)

Tags: c#, .net, 3d

Recently I've ran into a problem about 3D graphics. The problem is I have some sorted data (data is represented by a collection of dots with coordinates X, Y, Z). What I need to do is draw a coordinate system with three normals (X, Y, Z) and render those dots according to their coordinates.

Any help would be welcomed, but I would rather look at some real similar example how it's actually done.

Answer (score 2):

Try this [WPF 3D tutorial](http://www.kindohm.com/technical/wpf3dtutorial.htm). That's probably the best way to go these days.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise looking into:

- 3D WPF
- XNA
- Managed Direct X

[Riemers XNA](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/DirectX/Csharp/series1.php) might be a good place to start.

Transforming the co-ordinates 'by hand' may also be an option depending on what you need to do. This does involve matrix operations (as does all 3D) that I believe are explained on the same link.

You are probably looking to render a number of 'billboards / point sprites' at the data point, which are described in series two of Riemers tutorials.